# How to compare and display similar elements in array and display the index of each along with it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a use case wherein I have to compare two elements of an array and display the similar elements along with the index.
Suppose, I have two arrays say,

```
var array1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var array2 = ["Four", "One", "Five"];
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
array1 
One - 1
array2
One - 2
```

I have written the below code snippet to find out the similar elements in both the arrays but unable to proceed on the above.

```
const filteredArray = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));
```

Please help.

Comment: How for `array2` it should be one - 2 ? As one is in 0th index in array1

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over `array1` while updating the resulting list of common items having the value, index in `array1`, and index in `array2`
- In each iteration, using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), get the index of the current value in `array2`, if it exists, push a new item to the resulting array.

```js
const 
  array1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"],
  array2 = ["Four", "One", "Five"];

const filteredArray = array1.reduce((commonItems, value, index1) => {
  const index2 = array2.findIndex(e => e === value);
  if(index2 >= 0) {
    commonItems.push({ value, index1, index2 });
  }
  return commonItems;
}, []);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with basic `for` loops:

```
var array1 = ["One", "Two", "Five"];
var array2 = ["Four", "One", "Five"];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
         console.log("array1");
         console.log(array1[i] + " - " + (i + 1));
         console.log("array2");
         console.log(array2[j] + " - " + (j + 1));
     }
  }
}
```

Output :

```
array1
One - 1
array2
One - 2
array1
Five - 3
array2
Five - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

***Clarification :*** *How for array2 it should be `One - 2` ? As `One` is in 0th index in array1*

As per my understanding, You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) along with the [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var array1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var array2 = ["Four", "One", "Five"];

array1.forEach(item => {
  if (array2.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    console.log(item, array2.indexOf(item));
  }
});

array2.forEach(item => {
  if (array1.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    console.log(item, array1.indexOf(item));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if needed the index is

1. Check 2 arrays to see if they contain the same element
2. Check the indexOf() on each array for that value.

```js
// Set values
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
const array2 = ["three", "five", "four"];

// Find duplicates
const duplicates = array1.filter((item) => array2.includes(item));

const findDiffIndexs = (values, arr1, arr2 ) => {
  const indexes = [];
  
  values.forEach((value) => {
    const index1 = array1.indexOf(value);
    const index2 = array2.indexOf(value);
    
    const label = `Value: '${value}' is found in array1[${index1}] & array2[${index2}]`;
    
    indexes.push(label);
  });
  
  return indexes;
}

if (duplicates) console.log(findDiffIndexs(duplicates, array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way & store it in an object

```
var array1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var array2 = ["Four", "One", "Five"];
let obj={ array1:[],array2:[] }

array1.filter((value,i) => {
  if(array2.indexOf(value) !== -1){
    console.log('value',value, array2.indexOf(value))
    obj["array1"].push(`value - ${i + 1}`)
    obj["array2"].push(`value - ${array2.indexOf(value) + 1}`)
  }
});

console.log(obj)
```

**Output**

```
{ array1: [ 'value - 1' ], array2: [ 'value - 2' ] }
```